# Link "Watch on youtube" doesn't work from iOS UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api

I've embedded a youtube iFrame to play videos in a UIWebView web page.

The link "watch on youtube" doesn't work:

[image]

The code is:

```
<iframe name="player" id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$firstParsedVideo}?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0" width="279" height="155"></iframe>
```

where $firstParsedVideo is the video id.

I've done the same in a Cocoa Osx WebView and it works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that the web view Base URL is set to local. Since my web view load local resources (images), I need to set it to local. But this means that I can't load online resources (youtube videos). Either one or the other.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be the problem you can only set the base URL when loading a HTML string, i cannot tap this link when loading a youtube embed URL

Answer (score 2):

here is the real solution to the problem:

the "watch on youtube" link has a target = open in new window property, to circumvent this, here is the relevant code:

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
  if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

in swift:

```
extension YoutubeView: WKUIDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if !(navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame ?? false) {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same issue specifically with YouTube embeds. The WKNavigationDelegate was receiving events for everything except tapping on the title. I had no idea it was triggering the WKUIDelegate instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Apple does not let you play Youtube videos in a WebView in your own app and they'll also reject your app. Because I have this experience before.

Btw I wrote a method to play Youtube videos in my app:

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)videoId frame:(CGRect)frame {

NSString* embedHTML = @"\
   <html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
   <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
   </body></html>";
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoId, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

Hope it helps.